# How to return object from django with react?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

How to send id of object with React to django and return data of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios:

```
import axios from "axios";

getObject(id) {
    return axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${id}/`);
};

getObject(objectID)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

If You need to send object data from React to Django Backend You can send POST request, like this:

```
createObject(data) {
    return axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", data);
};

createObject(data)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
```

or `PUT` request:

```
updateObject(id, data) {
    return axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${id}/`, data);
};

updateObject(
        objectID,
        data
      )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
```

Comment: can I do the same with fetch?

Comment: Yes, You can use fetch too.

Comment: But I need to send object data with react and receive it in django